# How to create a single page PDF file out of multiple EPS files with GhostScript

Tags: pdf, conversion, ghostscript

I'm trying to merge eps files into a pdf file using GS, however, I cannot get it to put multiple eps files without page breaks in between even if original files are small. The command I'm using is:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out_file [list of eps files...]
```

Answer (score 5):

I decided to write a simple script to generate a tex file that includes eps file arguments 
(using `\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{arg1.eps} ...`). Then using latex, and dvipdf I can get a pdf file with multiple eps files on a page.

Answer (score 0):

I merged a handful of pdf's into a single document using `pdftk *.pdf output all.pdf`. So that leaves you with a converting EPS documents to PDF: [How to convert PDF to EPS?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20883/how-to-convert-pdf-to-eps)

Comment: Does it merge multiple pdf's into a single page?

Comment: @perreal No, pdftk does not merge multiple pages into one single page - except the background and stamp operation, but they are for other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`psmerge`](http://starlink.eao.hawaii.edu/devdocs/sun164.htx/sun164se2.html#x3-40002)!

```bsh
psmerge picture1.eps picture2.eps > merged.ps
```